# Can we upgrade csvhelper.dll

Tags: 2sxc

for some dnn module, we need to use a newer version of csvhelper.dll.
2sxc uses 2.16.3 and the module we want to use, uses version 12.1.2.
So that is a big difference....
What are the options we have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply try to replace the DLL, my guess is it should just work. If it doesn't, you can put the 2sxc-dll in a subfolder \bin\2sxc and add a dll-redirect into the web.config.

If you look at 2sxc 10.04, you'll see that we did just that for some DLLs because DNN 9.4 will have a similar DLL version issue.